# How do I use Webstorm's LiveEdit with local server

Tags: webstorm

I have my local server pointed to a URL, for example: www.thing.com.

Can I get Webstorm's LiveEdit feature to work like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be supported in the next plug-in update, [see the related bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13227).